# Prove that $\sin(ax+b)$ is continuous using $|\sin x| < |x|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, continuity

> Prove that $\sin(ax+b)$ is continuous using $|\sin x| < |x|$

I would like to ask for verification of my proof. Essentially to obtain a proof we need to show that:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\sin(ax+b) = \sin(ax_0 + b)
$$
or:
$$
|x-x_0| < \delta_\epsilon \implies |\sin(ax+b) - \sin(ax_0+b)| < \epsilon
$$

I've started with rewriting the RHS of the implication:
$$
\begin{align}
|\sin(ax+b) - \sin(ax_0+b)| &= \left|2\sin\left(\frac{ax+b - ax_0 - b}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{ax + b + ax_0 + b}{2}\right)\right| \\
&= \left|2\sin\left(\frac{ax+b - ax_0 - b}{2}\right)\right|\left|\cos\left(\frac{ax + b + ax_0 + b}{2}\right)\right| \\
&= \left|2\sin\left(\frac{ax- ax_0}{2}\right)\right|\underbrace{\left|\cos\left(\frac{ax + ax_0 + 2b}{2}\right)\right|}_{\le 1} \\
&\le \left|2\sin\left(\frac{ax- ax_0}{2}\right)\right| \\
&\le \left|2\left(\frac{ax- ax_0}{2}\right)\right| \\
&= |ax-ax_0| \\
&= |a||x-x_0|
\end{align}
$$

Now chose $\delta = {\epsilon \over |a|}$, then:
$$
\forall x:|x-x_0| < \delta \implies |\sin(ax + b) - \sin(ax_0 + b)| < \epsilon
$$

I have some doubts regarding the last statement. Could you please confirm my reasoning is fine or propose an improvement/correct-proof in case the above makes no sense.

Comment: I think you need to choose $\delta = {\epsilon\over |a|}$

Comment: If $a=0$, then your function is constant and therefore continuous. Otherwise, take $\delta = \varepsilon/|a|$ and by your computation, $  |\sin(ax+b)-\sin(ax_0+b)|\leq \varepsilon  $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct except for a minor glitch. If $a=0$ you cannot set $\delta=\epsilon/|a|$, but that's easily fixed: in this case set $\delta=1$ (or your preferred positive number).

You have indeed proved that, for $a\ne0$, if $|x-x_0|<\delta=\varepsilon/|a|$ one has
$$
\lvert\sin(ax+b)-\sin(ax_0+b)\rvert\le
|a||x-x_0|<|a|\frac{\epsilon}{|a|}=\epsilon
$$
and therefore
$$
\lvert\sin(ax+b)-\sin(ax_0+b)\rvert<\epsilon
$$